# What is called within a sagemaker custom (training) container?

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

Somewhere this spring the behaviour of the sagemaker docker image changed and I cannot find the way I need to construct it now.

**Directory structure**

```
/src/some/package
/project1
    /some_entrypoint.py
    /some_notebook.ipynb
/project2
    /another_entrypoint.py
    /another_notebook.ipynb
setup.py
```

**Docker file**

Note that I want to shift tensorflow version, so I changed the `FROM` to the latest version. This was the
breaking change.

```
# Core
FROM 763104351884.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/tensorflow-training:2.3.0-cpu-py37-ubuntu18.04

COPY . /opt/ml/code/all/
RUN pip install /opt/ml/code/all/

WORKDIR "/opt/ml/code"
```

**Python code**

This code should start the entrypoints, for example here we have the code of some_notebook.ipynb. I tried all possible combinations of working directory + source_dir (None, '.', or '..'), entry_point (with or without /), dependencies ('src')...

- if setup is present it tries to call my project as a module (python -m some_entrypoint)
- if not, it often is not able to find my entrypoint. Which I don't understand because the TensorFlow is supposed to add it to the container, isn't it?

```
estimator = TensorFlow(
   entry_point='some_entrypoint.py', 
   image_name='ECR.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/overall-project/sagemaker-training:latest',
   source_dir='.',
#    dependencies=['../src/'],
   script_mode=True,

   train_instance_type='ml.m5.4xlarge',
   train_instance_count=1,
   train_max_run=60*60,  # seconds * minutes
   train_max_wait=60*60,  # seconds * minutes. Must be >= train_max_run
   hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
   metric_definitions=metrics,
   role=role,
   framework_version='2.0.0',
   py_version='py3',
  )
estimator.fit({
    'training': f"s3://some-data/"}
#   , wait=False
)
```

Ideally I would want to understand the logic within: what is called given what settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the training container runs, your entry_point script will be executed.

Since your notebook file and entry_point script are under the same directory, your `source_dir` should just be "."

Does your entry_point script import any modules that are not installed by the tensorflow training container by default? Also could you share your stacktrace of the error?